# tryin to reset the radio when the show/hide is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

The code below works perfect id i need to show and hide the contents of a div. now the issue i am facing is the div's which are linked to the show/hide functionality has radio buttons inside them and that radio butons have have furthur functionality of show hide.

what I am trying now is: when the content is hidden, it should reset all radio buttons inside it to the default state: by this means whatever was checked prior to opening the show/hide or whatever the functionality was when page initially loaded.

Here is my code:

JS Code:

```
function hideShoowTab(ctb) {
    var ptb = document.getElementById("ptbname").value
    if(document.getElementById("ptbname").value=="") {
        document.getElementById("content"+ctb).style.display="block";
    }
    else if(ptb==ctb) {
        if(document.getElementById("content"+ctb).style.display=="block") {
            document.getElementById("content"+ctb).style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("content"+ctb).style.display="block";
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("content"+ptb).style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("content"+ctb).style.display="block";
    }
    document.getElementById("ptbname").value=ctb;
}
```

HTML

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="shipping1" onclick="hideShoowTab('1');">Shipping</a></li>

<input type="hidden" id="ptbname" name="ptbname" value="1">
        <div id="content1" style="display:none">
           -- content goes here with furthur radio uttons etc --
</div>
```

**well, No Jquery Please**

Comment: Why don't you refresh the page when a button is pressed? Also why no Jquery?

Comment: In the same `if condition` where you `block` the `div`, you could add `document.getElementById("id").checked = false;` which `resets` the value of the radio button.

Comment: Dojo is an Option, No Jquery as I am working on WCS

Answer (score 0):

When you hide radio button, put below line into javascript function.

```
 document.getElementById("radiobutton_id").checked = false;
```

This will reset the value of radiobutton.

Comment: but what about the code associated or function associated with the radiobutton being reset

Comment: What kind of functionality. Could you please explain?